# Consulta contando por diferença de data

Tags: mysql, data

Preciso fazer uma consulta MySQL que faça o seguinte:

Contar a quantidade de vezes que um mesmo registro aparece com diferença maior que 15 dias, ou seja:

- Registro 1 - Data: 20/01/2015
- Registro 2 - Data: 22/01/2015
- Registro 3 - Data: 03/03/2015

Nesse caso seria 2 porque contaria o 1, o 3 e desprezaria o 2 pois a diferença entre 1 e 2 é menor que 15 dias.

Tentei montar o seguinte mas não funciona:

```
UPDATE `logpro` SET `log`= (SELECT data, count(CAId) From `logpro` 
Group by FLOOR(LOG(Datepart(day, data))/LOG(15))
```

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é isto o que pretende.

A seguinte *query* conta, para cada registo da tabela, a quantidade de registos que têm a data com uma diferença superior a 15 dias em relação ao registo em análise.

```
SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(data,'%Y/%c/%d') as data,
(SELECT COUNT(data) FROM datas as d2 
       WHERE d2.data > (d1.data + INTERVAL 15 DAY)) quant
FROM datas as d1
```

Veja no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/786cf/8)

Comment: Acho que não é bem isso que o AP quer. "um mesmo registro" Acho que é um registro com um `idRegistro` igual.

Comment: Acho que é isto que ele quer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04e587/2

Comment: @JorgeB. Sim, talvez seja isso. Coloque como resposta.

Comment: Não vale a pena @ramaral, foste tu que respondeste, deixa ver o que diz o AP e depois se necessário alteras tu.

Comment: Não funcionou...

Comment: Se você postasse a estrutura da tabela e um exemplo de 3, 4 registos com valores talvez fosse mais fácil ajudar.