# Como fazer uma query que consulte apenas o DIA de uma data?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho um banco MYSQL e preciso de um SQL que consulte o DIA DE PAGAMENTO no campo DIA (este campo terá apenas o DIA do mês que o cliente escolheu para efetuar o pagamento, este campo é do tipo INT) e me exiba algum registro sempre que faltar menos de 5 dias para o dia de pagamento. Claro que este campo DIA se baseará no dia da data atual.

Tenho este código:

```
Select * from conta where DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) - 5 = dia;
```

Só que não funciona, pois ele mostra apenas os registros que faltam 5 dias para o vencimento, ou seja, se faltar 4 dias, 03 dias, 02 dias, 01 dia ele não mostra nada. Preciso de algo que sempre exiba algum resultado quando restar menos de 5 dias para o vencimento.

Comment: @DiegoF vou remover os negritos. verdade. rss Editei minha questão, tem como me dar uma ajuda?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Consulta contando por diferença de data](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58255/consulta-contando-por-diferen%c3%a7a-de-data)

Answer (score 4):

```
Select * from tabela where DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE())-5 = colunaDia;
```

Comment: Dá certo não amigo. Nada como resposta.

Comment: [DAYOFMONTH](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-dayofmonth-function.php) retornará o dia do mês a partir da data especificada [CURDATE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp) retorna a data atual , se a data for 31/03/2016 vai retorna 31. (31 - 5) =  26, se tive um usuário que page dia 01/04/2016 não aparecerá na lista.

Answer (score 1):

beleza ?

Cara, não sei como está sua estrutura de base, mas só utilizando o dia do pagamento fica bem mais complicado validar. Olha só uma situação, hoje é dia 29, se eu for considerar todo mundo que tem menos de 5 dias para vencer teria que pegar todo mundo que vai de hoje até o dia 3 de abril. Então se o teu cliente marcou que o dia 1 é o dia de pagamento dele você terá que considerar que "29" - "1" vai atender a sua regra de 5 dias, pois você está passando na sua dúvida que tem opção para trabalhar apenas com a data atual e um campo inteiro de dia.

Porém...

Se você quer controlar os vencimentos, seria interessante ter uma tabela com todos os lançamentos com seus respectivos vencimentos para frente.

Ex:

> Cliente deseja pagar algo, hoje dia 29/03, em 3x e o dia de pagamento dele será todo dia 10.

logo

> Tenho uma tabela onde vou lançar três movimentos para cobrança futura com vencimento de: **10/04/2016**, **10/05/2016** e **10/06/2016**.

Assim fica mais fácil e simples tirar a diferença das datas e verificar se a quantidade de dias é menor que os 5 que você deseja.

Qualquer coisa explica um pouco mais como está sua estrutura de tabela, sem conhecer o banco é um pouco mais complicado ajudar.

Se a minha sugestão foi útil, sinaliza ai!
Valeu!

Comment: Opa! Muito útil. Mas preciso apenas de considerar um campo DIA.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o *DATEDIFF* para fazer isso.

Na função você tem que usar a data atual no primeiro parâmetro no segundo você adiciona o total de dias que você que verificar a data atual ou seja **5** . *DATEADD(day,5, getdate())* com os dias adicionados basta fazer o `DATEDIFF`

```
DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE() , DATEADD(day,5, getdate()))

declare @Usuario table
(
  nome varchar(20),
  diapagamento int
)


insert into @Usuario values
( 'zé', 5),
( 'fulano', 15),
( 'manoel', 25),
( 'joao', 30),
( 'carlos', 5),
( 'zpauloé', 2)


select *  from @Usuario
where diapagamento <= DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE() , DATEADD(day,5, getdate()))
```

> diapagamento <= -- aqui retornará todos os usuários que onde falte 5
>   ou menos dias para o dia do pagamento.

***Bom, isso está em sql server mais a ideia é a mesma.***

```
Select * from conta 
where dia <= DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 5 DAY), CURDATE())
--where DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) - 5 = dia;
```

Comment: Tem como fazer esta query para mysql, pq não manjo converter de SQL Server para MySql

Comment: Veja se funciona, não dar para fazer muito sem conhece sua tabela.